# Когда использовать объект, когда статику?

Tags: php, ооп

Небольшой пример. Здесь класс Data служит хранилищем данных, в нём $pwd закрыта от изменения:

```
class Data
{
    private $pwd = 'qwerty';

    public function getPwd() {
        return $this->pwd;
    }
}

class DoIt
{
    private $pwd = '';

    public function __construct(Data $config) {
        $this->pwd = $config->getPwd();
    }
    public function myPwd() {
        echo $this->pwd;
    }
}

$var = new DoIt($config = new Data());
$var->myPwd();
```

Можно переписать на статическое свойство, но что бы закрыть её (переменную) от изменения, сделать придётся почти то же самое: так же понадобится дополнительный метод для её извлечения.
Вопрос: когда нам нужен объект а когда статические свойства и методы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы понять, стоит ли создавать статическое свойство - надо сначала спросить себя: а нужен ли мне экземпляр класса, для того, чтобы выполнить какое-либо действие. Например - у вас есть класс `ZooAnimal` и у него есть метод `numberOfAnimalInZoo`, который возвращает количество животных в зоопарке. Вы можете конечно создать объект животного и через него узнать это количество, а можете просто сделать метод статическим и вам не придется страдать ерундой. Плюс у статических свойств есть еще интересная особенность - они ссылаются на один участок в памяти. То есть, вы создали два объекта `ZooAnimal`, но при изменении статического поля в одном из них, оно изменится во втором объекте созданном на основе данного класса. Как один из примеров использования статики - паттерн singleton:

```
class Settings {
private $settings = array();
private static $_instance = null;
private function __construct() {
// приватный конструктор ограничивает реализацию getInstance ()
}
protected function __clone() {
// ограничивает клонирование объекта
}
static public function getInstance() {
if(is_null(self::$_instance))
{
self::$_instance = new self();
}
return self::$_instance;
}
public function import() {
// ...
}
public function get() {
// ...
}
}
```

И теперь мы можем создать единственный экземпляр с помощью Settings::getInstance. Надеюсь достаточно подробно смог расписать зачем статика и когда следует применять)

Comment: Ну про БД, singleton знаю, там нужен объект всё понятно. В остальных случах как понять когда нужен объект а когда нет. Допустим у меня класс с конфигурационными данным. Я могу их всех сделать static и получить.

Comment: @fosh4455 да, конечно можете. Тем более если конфигурация не зависит от конкретной реализации класса

Comment: Не так выразился, понятно что на статитке можно, но когда объект нужно?